# Why do I obtain the wrong total power when integrating this Fraunhofer diffraction irradiance pattern for a circular aperture?

Tags: optics, electric-fields, diffraction, intensity

I am looking for some help understanding something. I am working through my optics textbook (Hecht, 4th Edition), and am following the example of the far-field Fraunhofer diffraction pattern caused by a plane wave passing through a circular aperture. The situation is illustrated in the schemtaic below:

[image]

The book presents the general expression for the "optical disturbance" at a distance $R$ when using an arbitrary aperture, which is given as
$$
\tilde{E} = \frac{\mathcal{E}_A\; e^{i(\omega t - kR)}}{R}\iint e^{ik(ux+vy)/R} dS \tag{1}
$$
where the integration is over the aperture in the source plane. The book then goes on to calculate for the specific geometry of a circular aperture to arrive at the following result:
$$
\tilde{E}(\rho,t) = \frac{\mathcal{E}_A\; e^{i(\omega t - kR)}}{R} 2\pi a^2\frac{R}{ka\rho}J_1\Bigg(\frac{ka\rho}{R}\Bigg), \tag{2}
$$
where $J_1$ is the first order Bessel function of the first kind, and $\rho$ is the radial coordinate in the image plane (because the pattern is circularly symmetry). Finally, the book calculates the irradiance in the image plane using
$$
I(\rho) = \frac{1}{2}\tilde{E} \tilde{E}^* = \frac{2\mathcal{E}_A^2A^2}{R^2} \Bigg[ \frac{J_1(ka\rho/R)}{ka\rho/R} \Bigg]^2. \tag{3}
$$

My question is really regarding the scaling factors, because I am not sure what $\mathcal{E}_A$ really is. The book describes this as the "source strength per unit area", which is a bit vague to me.

In my schematic, I want the total power through the aperture to be the *input* to the problem, and am prescribing this to be $P=1$mW, so the irradiance at the aperture plane I know is constant at
$$
I_{in}=\frac{P}{\pi a^2}=\frac{1\textrm{mW}}{\pi (1\textrm{mm})^2}=318\;\textrm{W}/\textrm{m}^2. \tag{4}
$$
How do I use this number to calculate $\mathcal{E}_A$? I should also be able to calculate the electric field amplitude at the aperture using the relation (assuming constant phase across aperture)
$$
I_{in} = \frac{1}{2}c\epsilon_0|E|^2 \rightarrow E = \sqrt{\frac{2I_{in}}{c\epsilon_0}} = 490\;\textrm{V/m}, \tag{5}
$$
but it seems that this is not equal to $\mathcal{E}_A$?

Eventually, I would like to be able to check that when numerically integrating Eq. (3) over the entire $(x,y)$ plane, I obtain the correct 1mW of power (assuming no losses). To test this, I have created the following Matlab script, but it can be seen that when I integrate the final diffraction pattern I don't recover my original 1 mW of power. What am I misunderstanding?

Thank you!

```
P = 1e-3;              % Power through aperture [W]
a = 1e-3;              % Aperture radius [m]
I_in = P/(pi*a^2);     % Intensity at aperture [W/m^2]

c = 3e8;               % speed of light
e0 = 8.85e-12;         % vacuum permittivity
source_field = sqrt(2*I_in/(c*e0)); % 490 V/m

epsilonA = 1/lambda*sqrt(P/(2*A))*source_field;    % "Source strength per unit area" in Hecht language

A = pi*a^2;      % Aperture area [m^2]
R = 1000;        % Distance to screen [m]
lambda = 780e-9; % Wavelength of light [m]
k = 2*pi/lambda; % Wavenumber of light


% Image plane coordinates
x = linspace(-5,5,1000);y = x; % [m]
dx = x(1) - x(2);
dy = y(1) - y(2);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
rho = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2); % radial coordinate

% Calculate diffraction pattern (Hecht, Optics)
I = 2 * epsilonA^2 * A^2 / R^2 * (besselj(1,k*a*rho/R)./(k*a*rho/R)).^2; 

% Check total power in diffraction pattern
power_image_plane = sum(sum(I))*dx*dy; % gives wrong value of 2.3e-13 Watts
```

[image]

Comment: @hyportnex Did you mean $E = \mathcal{E}_A A$ then? Is "strength" commonly understood to mean something specific? If I replace ```epsilonA = source_field;``` with ```epsilonA = source_field/A;``` in the code, then I still get the wrong result (60 $\mu$W).

Comment: yes, that "square" was a typo; I wanted to write $E=\mathcal{E}_A A$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112255/discussion-between-hyportnex-and-teeeeee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will follow Born&Wolf [1] Sections 8.3.3 and 8.5.2 according to which, see eq (10)

$$U(\mathcal{P})= 2\pi\mathcal{C} \int_0^a J_0(k\rho w)\rho d\rho \tag{8.5.10}\label{10}$$where $$\mathcal{C}=\frac{1}{\lambda R}\sqrt{\frac{\mathcal{\dot E}}{\mathcal{D}}} \tag{8.3.42}\label{42}$$ and $\mathcal{\dot E}$ is defined as the total integrated power (energy) through (in) the circular aperture whose area is $\mathcal{D}=\pi a^2$. In the center of the screen the intensity follows from the Fourier transform relationship, see Parseval's theorem, (8.3.40) and is equal to
$$I_0 = \frac{\mathcal {\dot E} \mathcal {D}}{\lambda^2 R^2}=\mathcal{C}^2 \mathcal D^2 \tag{8.3.44}\label{44}$$

Now the diffracted power (intensity) over the screen at a point $\mathcal{P}$ that is at an angle $\gamma$ from the center line and a distance $R$ from the aperture is Airy's formula eq 8.5.14:
$$I(\mathcal{P}) = |U(\mathcal{P})|^2=I_0\left|\frac{2J_1(kaw)}{kaw} \right|^2 \tag{8.5.14}\label{14}.$$
Here $\gamma \approx w = \frac{\ell}{R}$

Now let us integrate $\eqref{14}$ over the whole screen. The area element on the *screen* in polar coordinates $\ell,\alpha$ is $\ell d\ell d \alpha$ but because of the circular symmetry of $I(\mathcal P)$ the integration over the angle is $2\pi$ and we get the total power deposited on the screen as
$$ K =2\pi\int_0^{\alpha_{max}} I_0\left|\frac{2J_1(kaw)}{kaw} \right|^2 \ell d\ell $$
Now let $x=kaw = ka \frac{\ell}{R}$ or $ \ell = \frac{Rx}{ka}$ then

$$ K =2\pi \frac{I_0 R^2}{(ka)^2}\int_0^{x_{max}} \left|\frac{2J_1(x)}{x} \right|^2x dx \\= 4\pi \frac{I_0 R^2}{(ka)^2} 2\int_0^{x_{max}}  \frac{J_1^2(x)} {x} dx $$

The integral can be expressed explicitly
$$2\int_0^{x_0}  \frac{J_1(x)^2} {x} dx  = 1- J_0^2(x_0)-J_1^2(x_0) \tag{8.5.12}\label{12}$$
and for $x_0 \to \infty$ the RHS of $\eqref{12}$ goes to $1$, and since $x=ka\ell/R$ this limit is the same as $k\to \infty$; therefore with $\eqref{44}$ we get

$$\begin{align}
K\approx 4\pi \frac{I_0 R^2}{(ka)^2} \\
= 4\pi\frac{\mathcal {\dot E} \mathcal {D} R^2}{\lambda^2 R^2 (ka)^2}
= 4\pi\frac{\mathcal {\dot E} \mathcal {D}}{4\pi^2 a^2} \\= \frac{\mathcal {\dot E} \mathcal {D}}{\pi a^2}= \mathcal {\dot E}
\end{align}$$

That is $K\approx \mathcal{\dot E}$, which shows that the diffracted power is the same as the one passing through the aperture within the paraxial (far-field) approximation.

---

The dimensions are consistent. If we measure the intensity $I_0$ in units of $\rm{W} \rm{m}^{-2}$, which is dissipated power per unit area, then from $\eqref{44}$ $[\mathcal C] = \sqrt { \rm{W} m^{-2} } \rm{m}^{-2} = \sqrt{\rm{W}} \rm{m}^{-3}$. Similarly, using $\eqref{42}$ we get $[\mathcal {\dot E}] = [\lambda^2 R^2 I_0 /\mathcal {D}] = \rm{m}^2 \rm{m}^2 \rm{W} \rm{m}^{-2} \rm{m}^{-2}= \rm{W} $ that represents the *total* power incident on the aperture, as it should be.

[1] https://archive.org/details/PrinciplesOfOptics/page/n433/mode/2up

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So can you write an expression for what Hecht calls $\mathcal{E}$? This is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: I am not familiar with Hecht but I think $\mathcal {D} = A$ and then from making $I_0$ the *same* both in your equations and that of Born&Wolf $\mathcal {E}_A = \frac{1}{\lambda} \sqrt{ \frac {\mathcal {E}} {2\mathcal {D} }} = \frac {\mathcal{C}} {\sqrt 2}$ Good luck!

Comment: Yes I thought so too. I have edited the expression for ```epsilonA``` in the Matlab code above to include this formula. However, it is still not integrating to give the 1 mW dialled in at the start of the code. Can you spot what might be wrong? Appreciate your help with this.

Comment: sorry, I can barely read my own code but the most likely bug is in the 2d numerical integration; try it on a simple example where you kn ow the answer.

Comment: No that is all fine, I have checked it like you say on a test problem. The issue is where $\mathcal{E}_A$ should be applied. It is often described as "source strength per unit area", which makes me feel like it should be used to scale the input electric field distribution within the aperture. Does that sound right?

Comment: Actually, I think what you wrote might be wrong. Your definition of jinc (your Eq. 8.5.14) has the factor of 2 inside the square. So, it looks like the definition should be $\mathcal{E}_A = \frac{1}{\lambda}\sqrt{\frac{2\mathcal{E}}{\mathcal{D}}}$ ?

Comment: what i wrote maybe wrong but not because of that: $2\pi \times 4 = 4\pi \times 2$

Comment: Okay, this almost makes sense now. There is one final thing that doesn't. In terms of the electric field inside the aperture, $E_0$, the "source strength per unit area" is given by $\mathcal{E}_A = \sqrt{c\epsilon_0}\cdot E_0/\lambda$. This gives it dimensions of $[\sqrt{\textrm{Watts}}/\textrm{m}^2]$. How can I interpret this? The "per unit area" obviously makes sense, but why "strength" seems to be in square root of Watts.